# Nginx rewrite rule with special character and Regex

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

We have URLs that contains `#!` in their structure. I would like them to be redirected.

From:

```
/#!/about/
/#!/about/example/
```

To:

```
/about/
/about/example/
```

I tried this rule, but it didn't work:

```
rewrite ^([\/][#][!][\/])(.+[\/])(.+[\/])$ /$2$3 permanent;
```

Comment: Browsers never send hash part to server, so you can't rewrite them on server

Comment: Any alternative you would recommend ?

Comment: The only one, do redirect in browser with JS

Answer (score 2):

Try this [much simpler expression](https://regex101.com/r/yG0rZ8/3):

```
rewrite ^/\#!/(.*)$ /$1 permanent;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. However it does not look to get #! properly. It works with normal character though : rewrite ^\/test\/(.*)$ /$1 permanent; makes /test/about/ redirect to /about/

Comment: @troyer try my updated answer. The `/` do not need to be escaped but the `#` ***does*** need to be escaped because it starts a inline comment.